# C3P0 in Java 1.5 fails: UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, c3p0, unsupported-class-version

According to documentation:

*c3p0-0.9.5-pre5 requires a level 1.5.x or above Java Runtime Environment. c3p0 works fine under Java 1.5.x and 1.6.x as well.*

But in practice i am getting UnsupportedClassVersionError.

I'm using Spring but not Hibernate with jdk1.5.0_14.
C3P0 v0.9.2.1 works fine.

Has anyone got this combo working ?

Comment: Please edit in the stacktrace.

Comment: Java 5 has been end-of-public-updates since 2009, you might want to consider upgrading to a more recent Java version

Comment: as Abel Pastur points out, the 0.9.5 is generating Java 6 classes. the 0.9.5-pre5 docs need to be updated (and will be before the actual 0.9.5 release...) it probably could compile to 1.5-compatible classes if you really need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/build.properties), you can see that version is compiled for 1.6.

```
# we compile against jdk 1.7, but output jdk 1.6 compatible classfiles.
jvm.target.version=1.6
```